# Can't switch login and register form in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am making a laravel based website and i have a login form and when i press "Register" i want to be switched with the register form but it's not working.Here is the code.
home.js:

```
$('.message a').click(function(){
    $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
 });
```

home.blade.php

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <title> AgroHelp Login</title>
      <link href="{{asset('css/home.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="js/home.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="login-page">
                    <div class="form">
                            <form class="register-form">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                                     <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
                                             <button>create</button>
                                    <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
                            </form>
                             <form class="login-form">
                                     <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
                                     <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                                            <button>login</button>
                                     <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
                             </form>
                     </div>
    </div>
    </body>





    </html>
```

home.js is in public/js/home.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> AgroHelp Login</title>
        <link href="{{asset('css/home.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> //** Add jQuery
        <script src="js/home.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="login-page">
            <div class="form">
                <form class="register-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
                    <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="email address" />
                    <button>create</button>
                    <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a>
                    </p>
                </form>
                <form class="login-form" id="loginID">  //******* add ID
                    <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
                    <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
                    <button>login</button>
                    <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>     //** Missed the closing tag
</html>
```

Add this to you `home.js` file

```
#loginID{
  display:none;
}
```

Working CODE SNIPPET

```js
$('.message a').click(function(){
    $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
 });
```

```css
#loginID{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title> AgroHelp Login</title>
    <link href="{{asset('css/home.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/home.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="login-page">
        <div class="form">
            <form class="register-form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
                <input type="text" placeholder="email address" />
                <button>create</button>
                <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a>
                </p>
            </form>
            <form class="login-form" id="loginID">
                <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
                <button>login</button>
                <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It was in code.Here was missing.this is not the prbolem.But thanks anyway.

Comment: Not working.The code is good i think becouse in codepen,io is working.But in laravel structure is the problem i think.

Comment: Have you referenced jQuery library before including home.js? What's the error showing in console, when you click anchor tag?

Comment: i think i was not referenced.But how to do it?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) this is the error

Comment: Try <script src="{{ asset('js/home.js') }}"></script>

Comment: Also include <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> just before above <scrupt> tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="login-page">
                    <div class="form">
                        <form id="a" class="register-form">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                                     <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
                                             <button>create</button>
                                   <p class="login">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
                            </form>
                        <form id="b" class="login-form">
                                     <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
                                     <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                                            <button>login</button>
                                             <p class="register">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>

                             </form>
                     </div>
    </div>
```

Here are the script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.register-form').hide();
        $('.login-form').show();

        $('.register').click(function () {
            $('.register-form').show();
            $('.login-form').hide();
        });
        $('.login').click(function () {
            $('.register-form').hide();
            $('.login-form').show();
        });
    });
```